# Some questions about Ubuntu permissions and shortcuts

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, netbeans, sudo

I just downloaded Eclipse IDE and Netbeans directly from the websites and installed then in my Ubuntu 12.04. I have some questions:

1 - How can I add their shortcuts in the Ubuntu's sidebar? 
2 - When I add shortcuts in desktop using the gnome-desktop-item-edit app, I can't have super user permissions to manipulate then, the Netbeans IDE (that uses a script file to start) shows lots of erros telling that some files are read-only. How can I add sudo privileges in a launcher created with gnome-desktop-item-edit?

Sorry by my poor english.

Comment: I believe Ubuntu's side-bar is your Favorites list. Right-clicking the program icon in the desktop launcher thing (menu-like-object) should give an “add to favorites” option.

Comment: Can't find this option BRPocock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some days trying to find the better solution for my problem, I think that the better solution is first, Download Eclipse and/or NetBeans IDE from the Ubuntu Software Center and after:

- For NetBeans:
  Use the IDE's plugin's manager to download the needed ones, and make (if you want) an IDE update process.
- For Eclipse:
  After download, follow the steps of [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81341/install-eclipse-ide-for-java-ee-dev-via-apt-get-is-it-possible/81347#81347).

After follow this, you can easely create favorite links to your "sidebar" if you use Gnome 3 as me, or make desktop shortcuts without needing sudo privileges, just using the gnome-desktop-item-edit tool or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as question #1, first, open the program. Find its icon on the side bar, and right-click it, then select “Keep in Launcher.”

As for #2, in Ubuntu, you can edit the item to run with `gksudo COMMAND`, but that's extremely unwise (running anything with elevated privileges on the desktop. You should probably instead fix the permissions of the relevant files (right-click on the file, and give yourself permission)